# Compare dates from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I have a view which is exporting some columns, one column is called

`'created_at' type:"timestamp without timezone" format: "2014-03-20 12:46:36.590253"`

In rails I have a method, which is getting data from the view and is trying to filter the data by a date. I tried rapping created_at into date() but is still not working.
Any ideas?

`return ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("
    select * from db_functions where date(created_at) >= #{date_p} AND date(created_at) <= #{date_p}")`

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: date >= integer
LINE 2: ...select * from db_functions where date(created_at) >= 2014-03...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first noticeable problem is that your time is not quoted.  This is causing the time to be treated as integer.  To fix this, you could simply wrap `date_p` with quotes or use [`ActiveReocrd::ConnectionAdapters#quote`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L8) as:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
return conn.select_all("select * from db_functions 
                        where date(created_at) >= #{conn.quote(date_p)} 
                        AND date(created_at) <= #{conn.quote(date_p)}")
```

Another option, instead of converting each `created_at` to `date` in `where` clause, you could modify `date_p` to be beginning of the day value and remove the "date" conversion altogether.  Also, instead of using values directly in the query, it's better to use [prepared statements](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/22/show-some-love-for-prepared-statements-in-rails-3-1) (Linked article is a couple of years old, but explains prepared statements clearly with examples).

Then there is also the task of modifying the date time parameter to beginning of day.  Given that `date_p` is a string and not a time, here is what you can do:

```
date_p = Time.zone.parse("2014-03-20 12:46:36.590253").beginning_of_day.utc
return ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select * from db_functions 
                                                 where created_at >= ? 
                                                 AND created_at <= ?", date_p, date_p)
```